# How to determine if I am connected to a Philips hue bridge

Tags: android, philips-hue

I am trying to enable schedule feature in my android app. I want to make sure if I am in home network or outside network as schedule feature only works in home network (ie the network where hue bridges are connected). What is the best way to check this? I tried using this api "isAccessPointConnected" but it returns true when I am in outside network as well. Can someone help me to figure out the correct way to determine if I am in home network or outside network using any hue api?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a HTTP request to http://BRIDGE-IP/api/KNOWN-USER/config/ and check the response.